# MS graph API to get message returns invalid parentFolderId for a deleted message

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My objective is to confirm that a message deleted by user has indeed landed in "Deleted Items" folder.

I have a subscription that notifies me for changeType = deleted. With this subscription I get a notification like this -

```
{
    u '@odata.type': u '#microsoft.graph.message',
    u '@removed': {
        u 'reason': u 'deleted'
    },
    u 'id': u 'AAkALgAAAAAAHYQDEapmEc2byACqAC-EWg0AQ4KiMeupd0KGRfRTWvssWQAAZpGrnAAA'
}
```

I then take this message id, and query the server to get the message. I hoped that the parent folder id in the message will tell me if the message was moved to "Deleted Items" folder

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAkALgAAAAAAHYQDEapmEc2byACqAC-EWg0AQ4KiMeupd0KGRfRTWvssWQAAZpGrnAAA
```

This API succeeds and I get a response back with message object. However the parentFolderId value is invalid - i.e. it does not match with any existing folder ids that I get from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders

Has anyone faced such issue?
On getting a notification for deletion, how can I confirm that the message has indeed landed in the "Deleted Items"

Appreciate all the help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried getting the folder using that ID to verify it is invalid?

I just did some testing here, and the result is going to depend on how the user deleted the item.

If they just pressed "Delete" (or used the delete button in the UI, etc.), it would be moved to Deleted Items. In this case, you get a `deleted` notification, and the `parentFolderId` coincides with Deleted Items.

If they pressed SHIFT+DELETE, the client asks to confirm if you want to "permanently delete" the item. If they're set up with deleted items retention (which is on by default), then it isn't *really* permanently deleted. It's copied to a special folder so that the user can restore it within the configured undo period (30 days is the default I believe). In this case, the `parentFolderId` coincides with this special folder. Using Graph Explorer, I see this when I do a `GET /me/mailfolders/{id}`:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('deeb074f-40b0-4a1f-a471-7baab44c0026')/mailFolders/$entity",
    "id": "AQMkAGUyN2I4N2RlLTEzMTAtNDBmYy1hODdlLTY2ADU0MDgxNjBhMGYALgAAAzYn1Af8O8xErekG37ysDqcBAK48gWNswSROgdxWdCKszmoAAAIBHQAAAA==",
    "displayName": "Deletions",
    "parentFolderId": "AQMkAGUyN2I4N2RlLTEzMTAtNDBmYy1hODdlLTY2ADU0MDgxNjBhMGYALgAAAzYn1Af8O8xErekG37ysDqcBAK48gWNswSROgdxWdCKszmoAAAIBGwAAAA==",
    "childFolderCount": 0,
    "unreadItemCount": 1,
    "totalItemCount": 1
}
```

Comment: I will give it  a try.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try getting the folder with the ID and see what I get. What we had done  though was get the list of all folders prior to deleting the email. And none of those ids matched the ID we got in the get message response.

Comment: Right. The Deletions folder is a system folder, not part of the normal mail hierarchy. You wouldn't see it in the list of all folders returned by the API by default. That only shows folders visible to mail clients.